# asp.net mvc - some files are not gzipped

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compression, gzip

Interestingly some static files are gzipped some are not (specifically ckeditor.js). What might be the cause? Config section is below:

```
<dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="14.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
</staticContent>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This probably has do to with broken mime type mapping. Use this:

```
<httpCompression>
  <remove name="gzip"/>
  <scheme name="gzip" dynamicCompressionLevel="9" staticCompressionLevel="9" doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true"/>
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true"/>
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".js"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript"/>
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Use Fiddler to find out which mime-type your server is sending the JS files with. Verify that the file type is in the list.

Comment: I had the same problem and saw no change. But after I restarted the service (IIS only) then it worked as expected. So make sure you do that.