# Bizarre 80 port when GZIP, asp.net mvc2 + iis7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, gzip

GZIP can't work at **80** port for the **"text/html"** mimeType, though the rest of types do GZIP fine.
So i tried to change port to other one ,like **808 or anyone else**, everything became right. All the mimiTypes include **"text/html"** do GZIP fine.

---

**80 port Response Headers:**

**text/html** can't gzip

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:2469
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
```

**text/css** or any else type work fine

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:1550
Content-Type:text/css
```

---

**808 port Response Headers:**

all types include **text/html**  work GZIP fine:

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Encoding:gzip //became work fine!
Content-Length:1452
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8


Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Encoding:gzip // work fine like before
Content-Length:1550
Content-Type:text/css
```

---

1.**Environment** : asp.net mvc 2.0 + iis7.5 + windows2008 R2.

2.**IIS configuration** :   turn on **dynamic content and static content** compression, both **root site**(i mean the root node in IIS tree , sorry for that i don't know how to call it in english ) and **target site** .

3.**root site**: %systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost\ **applicationHost.config** :

```
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" doDiskSpaceLimiting="false" minFileSizeForComp="0">
            <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
            <dynamicTypes>
                <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />              
                <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
            </dynamicTypes>
            <staticTypes>
                <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
            </staticTypes>
        </httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

4.target site's **Web.config** : also open above mimeType:

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; q=0.5" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; q=0.5; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

solutions reference:
[asp.net mvc - some files are not gzipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336860/asp-net-mvc-some-files-are-not-gzipped)
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression

How can i make GZIP work for **text/html** at 80 port ?

Comment: This rather looks like a question for Superuser, not Stackoverflow

Comment: @fge,thank you, is't that mean i should move this question to Superuser.com? As u see, i'm fresh hand at here.